# Is it possible to use the Canonical Landscape API to get script output?

Tags: api, ubuntu, landscape

The documentation I can find for the Canonical Landscape API lets you do lots of things with scripts, but I can't find anything suggesting that you can get output.  However, if you use the Canonical web interface, script output is available, so it's presumably exposed somehow...?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue as well and since you're the first hit right now on google, I wanted to share the answer for everyone - if you run ExecuteScript on a landscape client and get back an ID of 123, and let's assume the job finished already - you want to then use that ID to ask the GetActivities API, with an input argument of "query" with value "parent-id:123".  If there is a result there, you will find the script output you are looking for under the result_text field of the response.  Good luck!!! It worked over here very well.